# Taxing GoFundMe Donations

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I'm like 99% sure this would not be income for us.  Reason why is because it will never be associated with any of our bank accounts.  This money will be withdrawn directly to my sister's account.

My uncle is a CPA and called me mentioning closing my GoFundMe account before it reaches 20000.  He said I will pay taxes on it if it reaches that amount.  However this money is going to my sister's account and will never touch mine.  But we are likely to have 200 donors.  Will I be held liable for taxes? Or does anyone have more on this?

I mentioned to my uncle that this money will never reach any of my accounts.  He was unsure whether or not I would still be liable.  So I am asking if anyone knows the legality of that? So maybe I should cross post in legal? Thanks!

Comment: You are going to ignore the advice of a CPA in favor of random people on the internet?  Say that out loud until the silliness sinks into your brain.

Comment: I didn't need to say it aloud.  You're right it is silly.  My plan is to stop accepting donations at 19000 and have another one open by someone else.  But I really want to know if I would be on the hook for this if the money never reaches any of my accounts?

Comment: Hiding income is tax fraud.

Comment: You are asking about income tax but forgot to tag with your country. Income tax laws vary substantially from one location to another.

Comment: @PeteB.: Well, there seems to be pretty strong evidence that the CPA is wrong here (or has been misunderstood).  I certainly don't know of any rule that says taxability starts at $20,000.  The link below shows the income will be *reported* when it reaches that level, but that's irrelevant to whether it is taxable.  If it were me I would get a second opinion from another accountant, preferably one who has some experience with crowdfunding.

Comment: Caution with your "open another account" plan.  Structuring transactions to avoid income reporting requirements can in some cases be a serious crime, even if the income in question was never taxable income in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.  I'm just trying to help my sister who has lost her husband and my niece and nephew who have lost their father.

Comment: @PeteB. given that the uncle's advice seems to be factually incorrect, ignoring it may actually be the right choice...

Comment: The only advice I would take from us internet is "talk to an independent CPA about your specific situation."

Comment: Whose money is it right now? If it's yours, then if you give it to your sister, you may be liable for gift taxes on it (but you can use your lifetime exclusion if you have one). Since it's your account, it's probably your money.

Comment: Also, are you married? If you are married, this might cost you since you cannot file jointly if you make a gift over $14,000 -- even if no taxes are due on it.

Comment: GoFundMe has a setup where you can assign the money to another person -- once you do so, you are unable to revoke it and only they can withdraw the money. Since you no longer have access to the money, it shouldn't be considered yours. Please review this on the GFM site and discuss it with your CPA to address your accountability and/or your sister's.

Comment: @DoktorJ I actually did this. Thank you for noting for others!

Comment: Side note - you can only really rely on a professional's advice, if you are paying that professional. That is the only way they will take responsibility for their advice. If you acted as your uncle proposed, and the IRS dinged you with taxes and penalties, would your uncle really pay your penalties for you? Because a licensed firm probably should. Free advice is good for a general understanding, but when it comes to something like this, I recommend either paid advice or your own IRS-supported research.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm going to post this as an answer because it's from the GoFundMe website, but ultimately even they say to speak with a tax professional about it.

> **Am I responsible for taxes? (US Only)**
>
> While this is by no means a guarantee, donations on GoFundMe are
> simply considered to be "personal gifts" which are not, for the most
> part, taxed as income in the US. However, there may be particular,
> case-specific instances where the income is taxable (dependent on
> amounts received and use of the monies, etc.).
>
> We're unable to
> provide specific tax advice since everyone's situation is different
> and tax rules can change on a yearly basis. We advise that you
> maintain adequate records of donations received, and consult with your
> personal tax adviser.
>
> Additionally, WePay will not report the funds
> you collect as earned income. It is up to you (and a tax professional)
> to determine whether your proceeds represent taxable income. The
> person who's listed on the WePay account and ultimately receives the
> funds may be responsible for taxes.
>
> Again, every situation is
> different, so please consult with a tax professional in your area.

https://support.gofundme.com/hc/en-us/articles/204295498-Am-I-responsible-for-taxes-US-Only-

And here's a blurb from LibertyTax.com which adds to the confusion, but enforces the "speak with a professional" idea:

> Crowdfunding services have to report to the IRS campaigns that total
> at least $20,000 and 200 transactions. Money collected from
> crowdfunding is considered either income or a gift.
>
> This is where things get a little tricky. If money donated is not a
> gift or investment, it is considered taxable income. Even a gift could
> be subject to the gift tax, but that tax applies only to the gift
> giver.
>
> Non-Taxable Gifts
>
> These are donations made without the expectation of getting something
> in return. Think of all those Patriots’ fans who gave money to
> GoFundMe to help defray the cost of quarterback Tom Brady’s NFL fine
> for Deflategate. Those fans aren’t expecting anything in return –
> except maybe some satisfaction -- so their donations are considered
> gifts. Under IRS rules, an individual can give another individual a
> gift of up to $14,000 without tax implications. So, unless a Brady fan
> is particularly generous, his or her GoFundMe gift won’t be taxed.
>
> Taxable Income
>
> Now consider that same Brady fan donating $300 to a Patriots’ business
> venture. If the fan receives stock or equity in the company in return
> for the donation, this is considered an investment and is not taxable
> . However, if the business owner does not offer stock or equity in the
> company, the money donated could be considered business income and the
> recipient would need to report it on a tax return.

https://www.libertytax.com/tax-lounge/two-tax-rules-to-know-before-you-try-kickstarter-or-gofundme/

Comment: Thanks @bobbyscon I read through that earlier.  But may be helpful to others reading

Comment: @MattJamison - You're welcome. I've added a bit from a tax website that mentions the $20k / 200 donors issue your uncle brought up.

Answer (score 8):

The $20k limit seems to be (from another answer) the threshold for GoFundMe to report the campaign. However, such a report does not change the taxability of the income. The income is either taxable or non-taxable regardless of whether the amount is $19,999 or $20,001. This is a common misconception, commonly seen when people think that income or gambling winnings are not taxable below $600, when in reality $600 is the threshold for issuing a Form 1099.

Given that, it would be foolish to close a wildly successful (*) GoFundMe campaign, because closing the campaign won't change the taxability of the income. But it will probably cut off the continued donations you may have received.

With the amount of money at stake, you should spend the couple hundred dollars to hire a CPA to look at your specific situation. Your uncle's comments are not specific to your situation at best, incorrect at worst, so don't hire him.

(*) I don't know what the median GoFundMe campaign raises, but I strongly suspect it's well below the $20k/200 donor reporting limit. Just because you have one campaign that's gone viral enough to approach that limit, doesn't mean if you close that one and start a new one, that it will go viral again, especially if it's under a new username.

Comment: Well, it's not necessarily foolish because the campaign is currently under his account. That means he is making a gift to his sister. Since the gift-giver is responsible for taxes, the IRS may well argue that this makes his brother responsible. If it were her account, she would be accepting gifts from random strangers, making them responsible. (If he has a lifetime exclusion, then it probably doesn't matter. But he may or may not, we don't know.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz added footnote. Closing a successful campaign would end the incoming stream of money, with no guarantee and (I'd wager) little likelihood that the replacement campaign will create a new income stream. And yet doing so does nothing to change the taxability of the first campaign.

Answer (score 4):

To echo part of stannius' response. If it's taxable, there would be tax on $19,999, just a bit less than on $20,000. Your uncle may have a credential, and members here may not, but still he may be mistaken. Or he could be giving you advice on how to skirt the law.

> The taxability and the $20,000 threshold are unrelated! Trying to 'avoid' the
>   $20,000 is a completely misplaced effort.

Gifts from anyone are not taxable to the recipient. So long as nothing is received in return, it's not taxable income to her. In contrast a blogger with a "tip jar" is soliciting money in exchange for advice, entertainment, etc. that's taxable. Donations to individuals, in the circumstance you describe are not income to her, nor are they deductible to the donor.

Edit - a fellow blogger (more than that, she's my tax crush) had an article [Cancer survivor gets $19,000 tax bill for GoFundMe donations](http://www.dontmesswithtaxes.com/2015/04/cancer-survivor-gets-19000-tax-bill-for-gofundme-donations.html) which may render my answer incorrect. Other article on this story suggest that the IRS is notified, but the nature of the transfer needs to be addressed.

In my opinion, you should find a new <strike>uncle</strike> CPA.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's not quite so straightforward as 'these are gifts and nontaxable'; in some cases the IRS has disagreed, though it's not always clear why.  I think the cases I've seen have all been cases where a third person is in between; basically, [people donate] -> GoFundMe -> Brother -> Sister, then it is possibly taxable as a single gift from Brother to Sister (though of course you should just file a gift tax form to get it covered under your lifetime exemption).  Even if the money flows to the sister directly, if the brother set it up there may be a technical issue.

Comment: Brother has already said the gifts go directly to sister. It's common for a relative or friend to set these accounts up, but not collect the money.

Comment: I'm just saying, I don't think the law is entirely straightforward here, even though it probably *should* be.  I think the CPA is not necessarily wrong in making sure they cover all of their bases (and I am not sure it's right to assume that the information from the CPA has been fully accurately transcribed here; not that OP misrepresented anything intentionally, but any time information goes from [expert] to [nonexpert] you lose information).

Comment: @Joe I was thinking the same thing, given that OP has some large misconceptions about taxation. That said, "close the campaign before it hits $20k" is pretty hard to misunderstand, and yet, is completely incorrect.

Comment: @stannius The uncle *might* be reasoning as follows: These are non-taxable gifts directly to his sister. So no paperwork should be needed on them. But the last thing he needs is to have to make that argument to the IRS. So better that they don't get notified because then, even if he's right, he may need a lawyer, will have the stress of dealing with the IRS, and so on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Maybe that's a good play if the donation rate had slowed down, and they are pretty sure that the donations aren't taxable, but don't want to risk the small chance of an auditor deciding otherwise. Otherwise they're trading an unknown but potentially large amount of money for an unknown but probably small risk.

Comment: @stannius And nothing looks worse than getting close to a reporting threshold.

Answer (score 0):

From WePay (GoFundMe's payment processor) support.

> I received only gifts and donations.  Will I receive a Form 1099-K?
>   As of 2015, the IRS has clarified that WePay is not required to send 
>   a Form 1099-K with respect to payments that are made solely as gifts
>   or donations.  The purpose of Form 1099-K is to report payments for
>   the provision of goods or services, which may be subject to tax.
>   Gifts and donations typically are not reported as income by recipients,
>   so it is not necessary to send them a Form 1099-K.

https://support.wepay.com/hc/en-us/articles/203609483-Tax-Reporting